# Run Integration test and Unit test using Maven in Scala project

Tags: scala, maven, unit-testing, integration-testing, maven-surefire-plugin

In my Scala project I have two packages such as "src/test/scala/integration" and "src/test/scala/unit". All the unit test and integration test are in their respective packages.
I want to execute them (either Unit tests or Integration tests) as per my need using commands like "mvn test". How can this be achieved?

Here is my "pom.xml" file -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sarfaraz.demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-project</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
  <description>My wonderfull scala app</description>
  <inceptionYear>2019</inceptionYear>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <scala.version>2.12.6</scala.version>
    <scala.compat.version>2.12</scala.compat.version>
    <failsafe.version>2.22.1</failsafe.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.48</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
      <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.27.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala/</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.21.0</version>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
          <junitxml>.</junitxml>
          <filereports>TestSuiteReport.txt</filereports>
          <!-- Comma separated list of JUnit test class names to execute -->
          <jUnitClasses>StudentRepositoryTest</jUnitClasses>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${failsafe.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*IT.scala</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <phase>integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I my case, while using "mvn test", I am able to run the Unit tests.

Here is the link to the GitHub repo: https://github.com/Sarfaraz214/ScalaDemo

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: You should use `mvn verify` this will run the integration tests as well as the unit tests...

Comment: It's only running the unit tests. @khmarbaise

Answer (score 1):

**There are 2 issues here**:

First, given your integration and unit tests have separate source and resource directories. you need to add extra source and resource directories by using the Build Helper Maven Plugin.

Second: Although you intended to separate your integration test using the configuration in fail-safe (**/*IT.scala) this would not work as intended in Scala as your tests are being run by your

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
<artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

I would answer how to resolve the first issue here and you could post another question on how to separate your integration tests and unit tests in Scala. (comment with a link to next question)

**Resolution to first (This will allow you to run both unit and Integration test)**

You need to add this to your pom file and replace the directory tags with the appropriate paths to your resource and source folder

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <executions>

      <execution>
        <id>add-integration-test-sources</id>
        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-test-source</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>src/test/scala/integration</source>
          </sources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>

      <execution>
        <id>add-integration-test-resources</id>
        <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <resources>
            <resource>
              <directory>src/integration-test/resources</directory>
            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>

    </executions>
  </plugin>
```