# How to run Scala Unit and Integration tests from Maven

Tags: scala, maven, unit-testing, integration-testing, scalatest-maven-plugin

I'm trying to set up Maven so that it can run both Unit and Integration tests using scalatest-maven-plugin, but I can't quite work out how to configure the plugin.

In source code terms my Unit tests are in files called `_____Test.scala` and the Integration tests will be in files called `_____IntegrationTest.scala`

If this were Java I would configure the maven-surefire-plugin as:

```
<execution>
    <goals>
        <goal>test</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

and the maven-failsafe-plugin as

```
<execution>
    <goals>
        <goal>integration-test</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

I want to do the same for the scalatest-maven-plugin, but with a different execution for for the Unit and Integration phases. My problem is that the includes and excludes configuration elements are not recognised by the plug-in. With out them I'm going to end up with all tests being run in all maven phases.

The author of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58557613/run-integration-test-and-unit-test-using-maven-in-scala-project) appears to have had a similar problem, but there isn't an answer.

Comment: If you have an option, add tag parameter to the test.  
Refer https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.0.6/org/scalatest/Tag.html

Example test looks like - `mytest("testname",Slow)` 

Then you can use `tagsToInclude` option for configuration element. 
https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin

Comment: @Amit, thanks for the advice, but tags are not going to work. The rest of the team can't be relied on to *always* tag tests, but they absolutely have to name their files. (besides its a tag per test, not one per file). What happens is that tests are developed, with out tags, and validate by running in IDEs. When Jenkins runs the tests the tags are not present so the tests get skipped. When bugs slip into the code the tests don't pick them up because they are not being run.

Comment: Try this. I could not find documentation about this suffix element though. 
`<executions> <execution> <id>test</id> <goals> <goal>test</goal> </goals> <configuration> <suffixes>(?&lt;!Integration)(Test|Spec)</suffixes> </configuration> </execution> <execution> <id>integration-test</id> <phase>integration-test</phase> <goals> <goal>test</goal> </goals> <configuration> <suffixes>(?&lt;=Integration)(Test|Spec)</suffixes> </configuration> </execution>`